# Unity 3d installing Standard assets for Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, assets

I have installed Unity 3d on my Linux system.I have downloaded the Window version of the standard assets (.exe) since there is no option for installation in Linux, I tried installing the Standard assets(.exe) through wine... but im getting an error that unity requires windows 7 or more... But since this is Linux i cant help it.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect `.exe` program to work on Linux out of the Box without the help of visual machine or some other software such as Wine.  You don't even need the `exe` program to install the Standard Assets. You can get it directly from the [Asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351) from your Linux.

It's recommended that you use other OS at this time because the Linux version of Unity is still in experimental mode and you may have problems with it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You just download unity using the following link,

[Unity 5.1 for Linux](http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/unity-editor-5.1.0f3+2015082501_amd64.deb)

It will contains standard asset also. Don't forget to select standard assets while installing.